# Cannot instantiate the type with regular Class

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, type-inference

So I have a class:

```
public class DynQSimModule<T extends Mobsim> extends AbstractModule
{

   private Class<? extends javax.inject.Provider<? extends T>> providerClass;

   public DynQSimModule(Class<? extends javax.inject.Provider<? extends T>> providerClass)
   {
    this.providerClass = providerClass;
   }

   //some methods down here
}
```

And when I try to call:

```
controler.addOverridingModule(new DynQSimModule<>(AMoDQSimProvider.class));
```

Eclipse tells me it "cannot infer type arguments for DynQSimModule<>. I understand this is because I haven't put anything in the <>, but the example code I building off of uses the same exact syntax and runs perfectly fine...

When I put in something like:

```
controler.addOverridingModule(new DynQSimModule<? extends Mobsim(AMoDQSimProvider.class));
```

Eclipse tells me: "cannot instantiate the type DynQSimModule."

I know that this is a problem when you try and instantiate an interface or abstract class, but DynQSimModule is neither of those...

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Using diamond operator is fine. I have experienced this error message with eclipse mars and the real cause was actually a missing import. Make sure you don't have any error on the line, for example missing import of AMoDQSSimProvider or  a typo in the strange class name, etc.

Comment: What is your jdk version?

Comment: I just installed the latest version of JDK and got this from my terminal:

    'java version "1.8.0_91"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)'

I am still having the "cannot infer type" problem though...

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are using JDK 7. If that is the case `new DynQSimModule<>(AMoDQSimProvider.class)` will not compile because Java 7 does not use target typing to infer type of the passed parameter.

`new DynQSimModule<? extends Mobsim>(AMoDQSimProvider.class)` will also not compile because you *cannot* use wild card notation in object creation.

To resolve this either you have to provide exact type in `new DynQSimModule<>(...)` or if it is possible, you could upgrade to Java 8 which provides target type inference feature.

For example below code will not compile in Java 7 but will compile in Java 8+:

```
public static void test(List<String> list) {
   // some code
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   test(new ArrayList<>());    // will not compile in Java 7 but it is legal in Java 8+
}
```

More on Java 8 [Target Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types).

Comment: I did java -version in my terminal and got: 

java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

I am assuming I have to install JDK instead of JRE?

Comment: You could use `javac -version` to check your JDK version. If it is JDK 7 then yes, you need to install JDK 8.

Comment: It says `javac 1.8.0_91`, does this mean I am running JDK 8?

Comment: Yes. How are you compiling your code? Using some IDE or from command line?

Comment: I am running the code in Eclipse. I followed some steps from google and apparently am running JDK 8 on Eclipse, so I am very confused as to why this is happening. I will check again.

Comment: Can you check what JDK version is being used in your Eclipse?

Comment: `-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/../lib/server/libjvm.dylib`

I went to Help -> Installation Details -> Configuration and this is what I found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116544/discussion-between-sudhir-singh-and-yousef-hindy).